# Why is there a difference in getsizeof() returns for Blender's python console and Python Shell? (for basic types)

Tags: python, command-line

This is a getsizeof() return for basic types in blender's python console:

[image]

And this is one (same args) in Python Shell:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be more about Python programing than about Blender or its Python API. I think it should be considered off-topic on Blender Stack Exchange. I think memory allocation may be different in different Python interpreters or versions, but you should ask this on platforms oriented more to programming to get a more competent answer. Stack Overflow may be a better place for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the usage of Blender or its Python API.

Comment: 1 an instance of an int  object in python?  Is there an expectation the value of `sys.getsizeof(1)` be constant?  (I do get 28 in python shell and blender's py console  on ubuntu 64 bit.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10365639/5317130)

Comment: It seems this might not be something that Blender is doing differently but something that most different Python implementations and versions do. I think it might be better answered elsewhere as well. Are there any situations where this kind of information might be useful to Blender users that I am missing?

Comment: Martin Z I hesitate to delete the question. Maybe, let the community decides.

Comment: batFINGER thanks for the link. It's really the answer.